# Can I rely on riak as master datastore in e-commerce

Tags: riak

In riak documentation, there are often examples that you could model your e-commerce datastore in certain way. But here is written:

> In a production Riak cluster being hit by lots and lots of concurrent writes, 
>   value conflicts are inevitable, and Riak Data Types
>   are not perfect, particularly in that they do not guarantee strong
>   consistency and in that you cannot specify the rules yourself.

From http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/crdts/#Riak-Data-Types-Under-the-Hood, last paragraph.

So, is it safe enough to user Riak as primary datastore in e-commerce app, or its better to use another database with stronger consistency?

Answer (score 1):

**Riak out of the box**

In my opinion out of the box Riak is not safe enough to use as the primary datastore in an e-commerce app.  This is because of the eventual consistency nature of Riak (and a lot of the NoSQL solutions).

In the [CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) distributed datastores (Riak being one of them) can only guarentee at most 2 of:

- Consistency (all nodes see the same data at the same time)
- Availability (a guarantee that every request receives a response
  about whether it succeeded or failed)
- Partition tolerance (the system
  continues to operate despite arbitrary partitioning due to network
  failures)

Riak specifically errs on the side of Availability and Partition tolerance by having [eventual consistency](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/Eventual-Consistency/) of data held in its datastore

---

**What Riak can do for an e-commerce app**

Using Riak out of the box, it would be a good source for the content about the items being sold in your e-commerce app (content that is generally written once and read lots is a great use case for Riak), however maintaining:

- count of how many items left
- money in a users' account

Need to be carefully handled in a distributed datastore.

---

**Implementing consistency in an eventually consistent datastore**

There are several methods you can use, they include:

- Implement a serialization method when writing updates to values that you need to be consistent (ie: go through a single/controlled service that guarantees that it will only update a single item sequentially), this would need to be done outside of Riak in your API layer
- Change the [replication properties](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/replication-properties/#A-Primer-on-N-R-and-W) of your consistent buckets so that you can 'guarantee' you never retrieve out of date data

> At the bucket level, you can choose how many copies of data you want
>   to store in your cluster (N, or n_val), how many copies you wish to
>   read from at one time (R, or r), and how many copies must be written
>   to be considered a success (W, or w).

- The above method is similar to using the [strong consistency](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/strong-consistency/) model available in the latest versions of Riak.

**Important note:** *In all of these data store systems (distributed or not) you in general will do:*

1. *Read the current data*
2. *Make a decision based on the current value*
3. *Change the data (decrement the Item count)*

*If all three of the above actions cannot be done in atomic way (either by locking or failing the 3rd if the value was changed by something else) an e-commerce app is open to abuse.  This issue exists in traditional SQL storage solutions (which is why you have [SQL Transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)).*